# conditionally integrate functionality from one header into another if it's included (is this even necessary?)

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, c-preprocessor

Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way because I spent so many years on C# away from C++ and I'm a bit rusty. I forget how good selective linking is.

This is really a multi-part question, and I'll start by describing the big picture.

I am building a JSON parser and query engine for low memory environments like IoT devices. They don't have a ton of space for code so I want the end developer to be able to only include parts of my library they intend to use. The pull parser is the core of the library so that's a given, but you might not need the in-memory trees.

Currently, lacking a better way, I have a #define HTCW_JSONTREE which i define in one header. It gets picked up by a 2nd header and a function is included in the 2nd header that depends on code in the first header.

```
#include "JsonTree.h" // optional
#include "JsonReader.h" // if JsonTree.h above is included
// extra functionality will be available from JsonReader
```

basically a parseSubtree() function that returns an in-memory tree will be available if you include both headers, but won't if you don't include JsonTree.h. It smells.

First of all, is this necessary, or can I just unconditionally include all the functionality and expect that parseSubtree() will never get linked in if its never used?

Second, if it is necessary, what is a better way to do it? Right now the includes are order dependent and the code reeks. I want to change it. Basically it's just in there now until I figure out something better because it's easier to remove than it would have been to add later if it turns out i need it.

Thanks in advance.

Here's more of what the code looks like:

From JsonTree.hpp by way of JsonTree.h:

```
#ifndef HTCW_JSONTREE_HPP
#define HTCW_JSONTREE_HPP
#define HTCW_JSONTREE
#include <cinttypes>
...
```

from JsonReader.hpp by way of JsonReader.h:

```
#ifdef HTCW_JSONTREE
JsonElement* parseSubtree(mem::MemoryPool& pool,JsonParseFilter* pfilter = nullptr,mem::MemoryPool* pstringPool=nullptr,bool poolValues=false) {
...
#endif
```

Where JsonElement comes from JsonTree.h as well. parseSubtree is my integration point between the two areas of functionality

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, is this necessary

Absolutely not.

> Or can I just unconditionally include all the functionality and expect that parseSubtree() will never get linked in if its never used?

You totally can. That's how all libraries in existence have worked from day one.